# Webpack advanced usage

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've been exploring `webpack` recently and I came across a few things I couldn't understand properly. I tried to find the answers a lot but couldn't get a proper answer. So here are my doubts:

1. When do we use `webpack-dev-server`? Is it some sort of server which runs my `express` code, if yes then how is it different from running normal `express` server.
2. How do I debug serverside code when I am running `webpack --watch`.
3. I was going through someone's git repo and I came across this code:

   `export default(DEBUG, PATH, PORT=9000) => ({
       entry: (DEBUG
           ? [
             'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhots:9000',
             'webpack/hot/dev-server'
           ]
           : []).
           concat([
               '.src/theme/theme.less',
               'babel/polyfill',
               'whatwg-fetch',
               './src/main'
           ]),
       output: {
            // some output path was given here.
       },
       cache: DEBUG,
       debug: DEBUG,
       devtool: DEBUG && "eval-source-map",
       // some other modules and loaders were here.
       plugins: DEBUG
           ? [
                 new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
                 new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
             ]
             : [
                 new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'}),
                 new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {allChunks: false}),
                 new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
                 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                     compressor: {screw_ie8: true, keep_fnames: true, warnings: false},
                     mangle: {screw_ie8: true, keep_fnames: true}
                 }),
                 new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
                 new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
             ]
   })`

   - I couldn't understand what exactly is happening at `entry`.
   - What is this `DEBUG`, it is being used almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> When do we use webpack-dev-server? Is it some sort of server which runs my express code, if yes then how is it different from running normal express server.

You could build something similar on top of Express yourself using [webpack-dev-middleware](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-middleware.html). That's what webpack-dev-server uses after all. There are also niceties like proxying, html5 history fallback, and such bundled. webpack-dev-server is just about convenience.

> How do I debug serverside code when I am running `webpack --watch`

I expect you could user [Node debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) or [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

> I was going through someone's git repo and I came across this code: ...

Looks like the author is using `DEBUG` to control the configuration so that you get HMR and debugging related bits enabled for debug (development) usage. During production those are skipped. That `entry` portion is needed by webpack-dev-server unless you are running it in the inline mode.

There are other, perhaps neater ways, to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still have some doubts, my server runs pretty fine when I use `webpack --watch`, then why do I need `webpack-dev-server`. Could you please elaborate a bit more what exactly is happening at `entry`, how `DEBUG` is helping to control configs for HMR.

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` comes in very handy with [HMR](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html). Esp. with React it's better than LiveReload. If `webpack --watch` works for you, perhaps that's enough. In this case `entry` configuration will concat the whole array into a single bundle. I would need to see more code to explain `DEBUG` in greater detail. There are probably separate files used to control the flag.